# Why are the CSS styles not being applied to the page?

Tags: css, symfony, twig, assetic

I am working on a Symfony2 application. I am customising the layout.html.twig file from the FOSUserBundle.

Any HTML changes I make within the file are immediately obvious when I reload the page in the browser.

I am using assetic to link to my CSS and JS files. They appear to have linked successfully, the files contents load when I click on their paths from within the source of the web page.

However the CSS classes I have specified on the elements of the page don't seem to be appearing with their styles applied. I can't figure out why this is.

Here is the syntax I've used to link to the JS and CSS:

```
    {% javascripts 
        'bundles/sysdevpunctuality/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'
        'bundles/sysdevpunctuality/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' 
         %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/sysdevpunctuality/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheets" href="{{ asset_url }}" media="screen" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Appreciate any tips on how I can go about debugging this issue.

Comment: Can you see the class names in the html source ?

Comment: Don't you have to set the `type="text/css"` on the link tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, try this syntax:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/sysdevpunctuality/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```

Of course don't forget to install assets:

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant comment but my suggestion is check the page source of the generated webpage, then you can check the directory where symfony is looking for the resources.